# Border is not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, less, user-interaction

I have the table in which I am tying to put the right border on my `TH` element , but strangely not working on IE 10.

I am using two table for my reason because this grid is dynamic and can update the values and also creates row from UI side and simultaneouslyread data from backend . It is completly working with chrome but to make it IE comparability, I am facing some challenges.

Code HTML

```
    <div id="consulta-cartera-grid-container" class="grid-container ui-widget ui-corner-all container-border" style="width:100%;font-size:11px;border-top:1px solid #949494;border-radius:6px;">
   <div id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-mask" style="overflow:hidden">
      <div id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-toolbar" class="button-bar" style="padding: 2px;border-top: none: ;"></div>
      <div id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-header" class="grid-header">
         <table style="height: 18px;overflow: hidden;display: inline-table;" id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-header-table" class="grid-table">
            <thead id="gridconsultaGridParams-header-row" class="header-row">
               <tr id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-header-text">
                  <th style="display:none;" id="gridconsultaGridParams-idHES" class="  " nowrap="">idHistorialEstadoSolicitud</th>
                  <th key="fechaCreacion" id="gridconsultaGridParams-fechaHES" class="  " nowrap="">Fecha</th>
                  <th key="descActividadFlujo" id="gridconsultaGridParams-actividadHES" class="  " nowrap="">Actividad</th>
                  <th key="descEstadoSolicitud" id="gridconsultaGridParams-estadoHES" class="  " nowrap="">Estado</th>
                  <th key="matriculaCreador" id="gridconsultaGridParams-usuarioHES" class="  " nowrap="">Usuario</th>
                  <th key="descTipoJustificacion" id="gridconsultaGridParams-justificacionHES" class="  " nowrap="">Deuda</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="gridconsultaGridParams-hidden-body" class="grid-table-body">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" nowrap="">No existen registros.</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody></tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-body" class="grid-body" gridid="gridconsultaGridParams" style=";min-height:20px;max-height:400px">
         <table id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-body-table" class="grid-table">
            <thead id="gridconsultaGridParams-hidden-header" class="header-row">
               <tr id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-header-text-hidden">
                  <th style="display:none;" id="gridconsultaGridParams-idHES" class="  " nowrap="">idHistorialEstadoSolicitud</th>
                  <th key="fechaCreacion" id="gridconsultaGridParams-fechaHES" class="  " nowrap="">Fecha</th>
                  <th key="descActividadFlujo" id="gridconsultaGridParams-actividadHES" class="  " nowrap="">Actividad</th>
                  <th key="descEstadoSolicitud" id="gridconsultaGridParams-estadoHES" class="  " nowrap="">Estado</th>
                  <th key="matriculaCreador" id="gridconsultaGridParams-usuarioHES" class="  " nowrap="">Usuario</th>
                  <th key="descTipoJustificacion" id="gridconsultaGridParams-justificacionHES" class="  " nowrap="">Deuda</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="gridconsultaGridParams-grid-table-body" class="grid-body">
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" nowrap="">No existen registros.</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS :

```
.grid-table th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px 15px 1px 5px;
  min-width: 16px;
  height: 18px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
```

Adding only important part of CSS which is not working

Comment: Have you tried `border-right: 5px solid #FFF;`

Comment: @LGSon yes also it is not working. It is working in Chrome

Comment: I tried this in IE10 and it worked (difficult to see though since they are white) ... get the feeling their might be something else causing this

Comment: @LGSon.. I have updated my HTML to look for a while please.

Comment: Any given `id` value can be used **only once per document**, that is, only one element can have it.